# Merging Php Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this two arrays:

```
$codes = array (
  0 => 'SW10055', 
  1 => 'SW10050',
  2 => 'SW10050'
);

$quantities = array (
  0 => '2', 
  1 => '4',
  2 => '3'
);
```

Each value of the first array corresponds to the value in the second array in the same position.

So 'SW10055' corresponds to '2', the first 'SW10050' corresponds to '4', and the last element of the first array 'SW10050' corresponds to '3'.

What I need is to create an array like this:

```
$result = array(
   'SW10055' => 2,
   'SW10050' => 7,
);
```

where the **keys** are the codes and the **values** are the relative quantities (added where the codes are the same)

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: @ewcz combine isn't what he want - note the duplicate indizies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrResult  = array ();
foreach ($arrCodes as $intIndex => $strCode)
{
    $arrResult[$strCode] = $quantities[$intIndex] + intval(isset($arrResult[$strCode]) ? $arrResult[$strCode] : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here first we are using `array_combine` to get keys and values, and then we are iterating over array to sum values.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/786921)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$codes = array (
  0 => 'SW10055', 
  1 => 'SW10050',
  2 => 'SW10050'
);

$quantities = array (
  0 => '2', 
  1 => '4',
  2 => '3'
);
$array=  array_combine($quantities, $codes);
$result=array();
foreach($array as $count => $code)
{
    if(isset($result[$code]))
    {
        $result[$code]+=$count;
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$code]=$count;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [SW10055] => 2
    [SW10050] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array and create a new array out of it

```
$result = [];
foreach ($codes as $i => $code) {
    if (isset($result[$code])) {
        $result[$code] += $quantities[$i];
    } else {
        $result[$code] = $quantities[$i];
    }
}
```